# Ignite ML with multiple preprocessing

Tags: machine-learning, ignite

Using Ignite machine learning, say I have a labeled dataset like this:

```
IgniteCache<Integer, LabeledVector<Integer>> contents = ignite.createCache(cacheConfiguration);
contents.put(1, new LabeledVector<Integer>(new DenseVector(new Serializable[] { 705.2, "HD", 29.97, 1, 1, 96.13 }), 2));
contents.put(2, new LabeledVector<Integer>(new DenseVector(new Serializable[] { 871.3, "HD", 30, 1, 1, 95.35 }), 3));
contents.put(3, new LabeledVector<Integer>(new DenseVector(new Serializable[] { 2890.2, "SD", 29.97, 1, 1, 95.65 }), 10));
contents.put(4, new LabeledVector<Integer>(new DenseVector(new Serializable[] { 1032, "SD", 29.97, 1, 1, 96.8 }), 4));
```

How would I use the NormalizationTrainer on features 0 and 5 but the EncoderTrainer on feature 1? I think I'm having difficulties understanding how to concatenate multiple preprocessing before finally feeding the model trainer.

What I currently have is this (modified Ignite sample):

```
        Vectorizer<Integer, LabeledVector<Integer>, Integer, Integer> vectorizer   = new LabeledDummyVectorizer<Integer, Integer>(0, 5);
        Preprocessor<Integer, LabeledVector<Integer>>                 preprocessor1 = new NormalizationTrainer<Integer, LabeledVector<Integer>>().withP(1).fit(ignite, data, vectorizer);
        
        Preprocessor<Integer, LabeledVector<Integer>>                 preprocessor2 = new EncoderTrainer<Integer, LabeledVector<Integer>>().withEncoderType(EncoderType.STRING_ENCODER).withEncodedFeature(1).fit(ignite, data, preprocessor1);

        KNNClassificationTrainer                                      trainer       = new KNNClassificationTrainer();
        KNNClassificationModel                                        mdl           = trainer.fit(ignite, data, preprocessor2);
```

Do I understand the multiple preprocessor correctly? If so, how would I add another BinarizationTrainer on feature 2? I think I'm getting confused by where to specify which feature to apply the preprocessing trainer on. For one trainer (NormalizationTrainer) I have to use the Vectorizer to tell which features to use, for the EncoderTrainer I can do this as a method function. How would I then add BinarizationTrainer with another Vectorizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One preprocessor builds on top of another.
Coordinates are relative to the preprocessor that comes before.

This example shows how to accomplish what you want to do:
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/ml/tutorial/Step_6_KNN.java

put a breakpoint here: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/eabe50d90d5db2d363da36393cd957ff54a18d90/modules/ml/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/ml/preprocessing/encoding/EncoderTrainer.java#L93

to see how the String Encoder references coordinates
examine all the variables:

```
UpstreamEntry<K, V> entity = upstream.next(); //this is the row from the file
LabeledVector<Double> row = basePreprocessor.apply(entity.getKey(), entity.getValue()); //after the previous preprocessor has been applied
categoryFrequencies = calculateFrequencies(row, categoryFrequencies); //use the given coordinates to calculate results.
```

more about preprocessing: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/preprocessing

Alternatively, you can use the pipelines API for a more streamlined approach to preprocessing: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/pipeline-api

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. Took some time to debug. I wonder though why in String Encoder the result of the basePreprocessor must be a row of a labeled vector with a Double label? Why is the label important for the preprocessing of the String features? Shouldn't this be a "<L> Type of label for resulting vectors."?

Comment: it looks like most preprocessing works with Double values only. For example when the next preprocessor after String Encoder tries to get features it calls its base preprocessor (String Encoder) but this fails for Integer features here: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/eabe50d90d5db2d363da36393cd957ff54a18d90/modules/ml/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/ml/preprocessing/encoding/stringencoder/StringEncoderPreprocessor.java#L89 with an Exception "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double"